# ng2 smart table custom,renderComponent

Tags: ng2-smart-table

I am new to Angular.I am using ng2-smart-table in my Project.in renderComponent Option of columns.Can i use parent Component in one Module and Child Component in another Module.

Answer (score 0):

If type is **custom** the **renderComponent** property must be defined.
Custom component that will be responsible for rendering the cell content while in view mode. Type must be custom in order for this to work.
You can see an example [here](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/blob/master/src/app/pages/examples/custom-edit-view/advanced-example-custom-editor.component.ts)

I am giving you the link that you can find the [documentation on smart table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

Comment: example link gives an 404 not found :(

Comment: I just checked the link is moved into another URL here is updated link: 
Please let me know

https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table